# MySQL read/Write very slow in a table because of long blob columns

Tags: mysql, database, performance, blob

In my DB a table contains 20 long-blob columns(columns can't be moved in another table) Each row contains a data size of 0.55 MB approximately. i created indexes on that table but it doesn't improve the performance.We need to store more than 1 million records in this table so i am planning to partition this table.
My question is whether Partitioning will improve the performance or not (Read/Write)?

Can anybody help me on this how to improve it.Suggest if any alternate way to improve.

Comment: Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `SELECTs`.  From those, we can better answer your questions about performance and partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the blobs into a separate table.

For example, you could have a table table1 containing the columns id and name, and another table table2 containing the columns id and data. If you only want the name, you don't need to query the table2 table at all; if you need both the name and the data, you can join the tables together using the shared primary key id:

```
SELECT id, name, data
FROM table1 JOIN table2 USING (id)
WHERE id = ...
```

Comment: Thanks Virendra,  but i already mentioned that all columns should be in single table.Our application will support sql server also if we spilt that table into multiple then we need to do lot of work in back end. can you suggest any other process to improve performance

Comment: why you are using blob for images or other

Comment: we are storing user fingerprints  in that columns in encrypted format to protect that information from outside.(10-FP, 10 - FP templates )

Comment: The images of the fingerprints could be stored in some folder with a pointer only in the database.more info see this [link](https://bytes.com/topic/data-management/answers/900937-how-store-compare-fingerprint-scans). i hope solve your probllem.